# magento2.4 get category collection filter by more than 1 or multiple products IDs

Tags: magento2

Just like

```
$collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $catIds);
```

This is a category collection based on $catIds array.

I wan a category collection based on $productIds array.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with custom query.

```
  $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
  $catIds=$connection->fetchRow('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category_id)
  as catIds FROM catalog_category_product where product_id IN('.$productIdsString.')');
  $catIds= $catIds['catIds'];
```